# Why would Samsung dishwasher door angle control the inlet valve?

Tags: valve, dishwasher, samsung

My Samsung dishwasher is not filling with water, but it doesn't notice and runs cycles to completion completely dry.

While troubleshooting, I found that it works fine if the door is open, with the door switch rigged to make it think it's closed. What's more, if the water inlet is on, and I close the door to about 3/4 closed, the inlet valve turns off! And if I open it back from there just a little, the inlet valve turns back on. I can continue like that, turning the inlet on and off by just opening and closing the door a little bit.

Further notes: with the door closed, the inlet valve input reads 60 V AC when idle, and 2 V AC when the dishwasher is trying to turn it on. With the door rigged to be open while running, it reads 120 V AC when idle and 124 V AC when the dishwasher is trying to turn the water on. Presumably that's correct, since it works for turning the water on, but I was expecting maybe 0 V and 120 V. Finally, the dishwasher does notice when it doesn't get enough water in that latter case, getting a 4C error code.  It doesn't get this error in the former case.

What could be causing this? A short somewhere maybe?

Comment: That 60V worries me. Mains, OK, near zero, OK, but half mains voltage and dodgy behaviour smells like a weak short. Do you have an earth leakage breaker (GFCI) on that circuit? Without one I'd be very wary of troubleshooting, especially with water involved as well

Comment: @ChrisH have the same worry. It is on a GFCI protected outlet under the sink.

Comment: Ok, so it's not shorting to the chassis and on to ground, that's good at least. Another possibility is a nearly broken cable inside the door, from the control board. The flexing of opening and closing could have caused the problem in the first place, as well as causing a variable connection. All the current to drive the valve going through one strand is likely to finish it off soon, if it doesn't cause deeper problems first